# A function that is $1/p^{\prime}$-Hölder continuous on $[a,b]$

Tags: holder-spaces

Let $g \in L^p([a,b])$ for some $p \in (1, \infty]$. Define
$$f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^xg(s)\ ds$$
for any $x \in [a,b]$. The claim is that $f$ is $\frac{1}{p^{\prime}}$-Hölder continuous on $[a,b]$, where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^{\prime}} = 1$.

So I need to show that there exists $M > 0$ and $\delta > 0$, such that for all $t$ with $|t|< \delta$, $|f(x+t) - f(x)| \leq M|t|^{1/p^{\prime}}.$ We have
$$|f(x+t) - f(x)| = \left|\int_a^{x+t}g(s)\ ds - \int_a^xg(s)\ ds\right| \leq \int_a^{x+t}|g(s)|\ ds + \int_a^x|g(s)|\ ds. $$
What should I do next? I seem to cannot find a way to use the fact that $g \in L^P([a,b])$. I must say that the condition $$\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^{\prime}} = 1$$ is very similar to Hölder's inequality. Should I use that too somewhere in the proof?

EDIT:
So after reading the comments, I decided to add some new discoveries. We have
$$|f(x+t) - f(x)| = \left|\int_x^{x+t}g(s)ds\right|\leq \int_x^{x+t}|g(s)|ds.$$
Rewriting $\int_x^{x+t}|g(s)|ds$ into
$$\left(\int_x^{x+t}|g(s)|^{p\cdot\frac{1}{p}} \right)^{p\cdot\frac{1}{p}} = || g^{1/p}||_p^p = ||1 \cdot g^{1/p}||_p^p \leq ||g^{1/p}||_p^p||1||_{p^{\prime}}^p.$$
Still, I don't see that this proves $\frac{1}{p^{\prime}}$-Hölder continuous$. I don't think the rewriting part is correct.

Comment: Is there something better you can do with $\left| \int_a^{x+t} g(s)ds - \int_a^x g(s)ds\right| = \left|\int_x^{x+t} g(s)ds\right|$, than just the crude triangle inequality bound?

Comment: And of course, you will have to use Hölder's inequality. A quick reminder: $\lvert g(s) \rvert = 1 \cdot \lvert g(s) \rvert$.

Comment: @Shaqinho I have added some new things using your comments. But I 'm still not sure how to show it. I have also used Teresa's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $t>0$: As Teresa said:
$$
\lvert f(x+t) - f(x) \rvert \leq \int^{x+t}_x \lvert g(s) \rvert~\mathrm{d}s = \lVert 1 \cdot g \rVert_{L^1[x, x+t]} 
$$
Now use Hölder's inequality: (Let $M := \lVert g \rVert_{L^{p}[a, b]}$)
$$
\lVert 1 \cdot g \rVert_{L^1[x, x+t]} \leq \lVert 1 \rVert_{L^{p'}[x, x+t]} \lVert g \rVert_{L^{p}[x, x+t]} = \lVert g \rVert_{L^{p}[x, x+t]} \underbrace{\lvert t \rvert}_{=t}~^{\frac{1}{p'}} \leq M \lvert t \rvert^{\frac{1}{p'}}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't we have $\lVert 1 \rVert_{L^{p'}[x, x+t]} \lVert g \rVert_{L^{p}[x, x+t]}$? But then ofc this will work only if $1/p' + 1/p = 1$.

Comment: Yep, you are right, thank you. I will edit that. In theory we do not even know if $\lVert g \rVert_{L^{p'}[a, b]}$ is finite...